# PHP session being destroyed after page reload

Tags: php, session, cookies, php-ini

Hey guys I am having some problems with my login and session script so I made a debug file to see what is going on

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo '<br>';
if(empty($_SESSION) || !$_SESSION || !isset($_SESSION)){
    echo 'empty';
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'LOL';
}else var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

When I reload it keeps printing `empty`

The problem came from nowhere two days ago, disappeared at least twice and now is back again. So it is coming and going all the time. My website behavior didnt change ever since, the amount of users is more or less constant and I didnt make any change in the code recently (last time was about 20 days ago).

By the way I think my **web-host** is always making changes in the settings but this time the problem didn't solve by itself or is taking too long

Comment: when you `echo session_id();` the id changes between reloads?

Comment: When i do this it works just fine, like you say yourself, your web-host is probably changing stuff without letting you know.

Comment: @violator667 nope the session_id stays the same

Comment: no! same id always. is there a way to check whether they are making changes that would affect the cookies or sessions? I mean, does PHP throws some sort of error or something?

Comment: it's not code issue - but server is acting strange - testing code on different machine is useless

Comment: @VictorFerreira hmm if the ID of the session is always the same (so session isn't destroyd) only session data isn't stored properly - do you have enaugh space on your webaccount? try to reach your host with this problem because you can't solve this on your own

Comment: @violator667 but what would explain the fact that it's getting fixed and becoming buggy from time to time? (assuming the problem is lack of disc space)

Comment: @VictorFerreira I have no idea - maybe is the heavy load on the machine, maybe someone is messing with software maybe some software is lounched from time to time and couses this. I could be guessing - but this is still just a gues. Write to your host.

Comment: alright. i am contacting them. many thanks